# Creating UITableViewCell through button press in another ViewController/ referencing UITableView in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm sorry if this question is too simple for all of you to answer, but it has been bugging me for a few weeks.

So I have a button in my FirstViewController

```
- (IBAction)levelOneButtonPress:(id)sender {
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

if(![self.eventField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    events *createdEvent = [[events alloc] init];
    createdEvent.eventDetails = self.eventField.text;
    createdEvent.dateDetails = self.dateField.text;
    createdEvent.timeDetails = self.timeField.text;
    [createdEvent combineDateWithTime];
    [createdEvent dateFormat];

    createdEvent.gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    if ([createdEvent.gregorian isDateInToday:createdEvent.eventDate] == YES) {
        NSLog(@"Date is in today");
        [todayEvents addObject:createdEvent];
    }
    else if ([createdEvent.gregorian isDateInTomorrow:createdEvent.eventDate] == YES)
    {
        [tomorrowEvents addObject:createdEvent];
    }
    else
    {
        [futureEvents addObject:createdEvent];
    }
}
```

}

todayEvents, tomorrowEvents and futureEvents are all arrays that I would classify my events into.

I want my user to input the details into textboxes which I will then collate, do some dateformatting and then add into the arrays.

Afterwards, I want the events to show on an UITableView as an UITableViewCell, so I've decided to write this on my SecondViewController(The viewcontroller with the UITableView in it)

```
NSMutableArray *todayEvents;
NSMutableArray *tomorrowEvents;
NSMutableArray *futureEvents;

@synthesize eventTable;

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section) {
case 0:
    return [todayEvents count];

case 1:
    return [tomorrowEvents count];

case 2:
    return [futureEvents count];

default:
    return 0;
}
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        return @"Events Today";

    case 1:
        return @"Events Tomorrow";

    case 2:
        return @"Events In The Future";

    default:
        return @"Unknown";

}
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"defaultCell"];

switch (indexPath.section) {

    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[todayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[todayEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tomorrowEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tomorrowEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[futureEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[futureEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
return cell;
}
}
```

However, when I ran my application, the UITableView did not even generate the rows when I've pressed the button.

Currently I'm guessing this is because I have to reload the UITableView but I can't seem to reference it in my FirstViewController to send it the message to reload.

Do I create an instance of SecondViewController in my FirstViewController.m file then call the reloadData method on that instance? Will it cause the UITableView to reload? I am a little confused on this part as I am not sure what happens in the background when the compiler runs the project. Does it initialize an instance of all the ViewControllers upon running? If this is the case, initializing another instance of the ViewController probably does not help.

Please also kindly tell me if theres any easier method to achieve what I intend to do with my app other than the method I am using right now.

Comment: Can you explain your view controller hierarchy?  Which is displayed first?  How do you get from one to the other?

Comment: Hi! @pbasdf All viewcontrollers are connected to a tabbedviewcontroller. The viewcontroller with the button is displayed first. I get to the secondviewcontroller by switching tabs using the default tabbedviewcontroller given by xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `FirstViewController`, you can get a reference to the tab bar controller through its `tabBarController` property.  The `UITabBarController` has a `viewControllers` property that is an array of the view controllers in each of its tabs.  So if your `SecondViewController` is in the second tab (index 1), you can access it from the `FirstViewController` through:

```
let secondVC = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers[1] as! SecondViewController
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually got it to work but I had to create a new instance method to call the reloadData method as the self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] does not recognise the reloadData method. Will Upvote once I have enough reputation points. Thank you very much